# Laravel not able to process queue model, but able to process code without queue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set up Events, Listeners and Jobs in one of my project. The code is able to run if I remove "implements ShouldQueue". But once I include implements ShouldQueue into the Job class, it stops working

My EventServiceProvider

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        'App\Events\IncorpPaid' => [
            'App\Listeners\ProcessIncorpReceived',
        ],
    ];
}
```

My Event Class

```
Namespace App\Events;

use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class IncorpPaid
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

}
```

My listener

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Company;
use App\Events\IncorpPaid;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ProcessIncorpReceived
{

    //use SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  IncorpPaid  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(IncorpPaid $event)
    {
        \App\Jobs\SendKYC::dispatch($event->company);
    }
}
```

And finally my problem code.

The following works. But the problem is using this doesn't queue the job.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SendKYC
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Company $company)
    {
        //error_log(print_r($this->company->puc,true));
    //  error_log(print_r($company,true));
        \App\Services\SendDocsForSignature::processKYC($this->company);
    }
}
```

But this queues the job but it doesn't work. $this->company returns a blank company model.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SendKYC implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Company $company)
    {
        \App\Services\SendDocsForSignature::processKYC($this->company);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last code snippet looks almost correct. You just need to declare the instance variable in which you want to store the `$company` value. In other words, you need to add `protected $company;` to your `SendKYC` class to be able to assign the `$company` value to `$this->company`.

You `SendKYC` class should then start out like this:

```
class SendKYC implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $company;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the catch. Appreciate it! I've been looking at this for hours.

Comment: It's a pleasure!